# Seaborn PairGrid: pairplot two data set with different transparency

Tags: seaborn, alpha-transparency

I'd like to make a PairGrid plot with the seaborn library.

I have two classed data: a training set and one-target point.

I'd like to plot the one-target point as opaque, however, the samples in the training set should be transparent.

And I'd like to plot the one-target point also in lower cells.

Here is my code and image:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

g = sns.PairGrid(data, hue='type')
g.map_upper(sns.scatterplot, alpha=0.2, palette="husl")
g.map_lower(sns.kdeplot, lw=3, palette="husl")
g.map_diag(sns.kdeplot, lw=3, palette="husl")
g.add_legend()

plt.show()
```

And the data.csv is like belows:

```
         logP    tPSA       QED  HBA  HBD          type
0    -2.50000  200.00  0.300000    8    1      Target 1
1     1.68070   87.31  0.896898    3    2  Training set
2     3.72930   44.12  0.862259    4    0  Training set
3     2.29702   91.68  0.701022    6    3  Training set
4    -2.21310  102.28  0.646083    8    2  Training set
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reassign the dataframe used after partial plotting. E.g. `g.data = data[data['type'] == 'Target 1']`. So, you can first plot the training dataset, change `g.data` and then plot the target with other parameters.

The following example supposes the first row of the iris dataset is used as training data. A custom legend is added (this might provoke a warning that should be ignored).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
import seaborn as sns

iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')

g = sns.PairGrid(iris)
color_for_trainingset = 'paleturquoise'
# color_for_trainingset = sns.color_palette('husl', 2) [-1] # this is the color from the question
g.map_upper(sns.scatterplot, alpha=0.2, color=color_for_trainingset)
g.map_lower(sns.kdeplot, color=color_for_trainingset)
g.map_diag(sns.kdeplot, lw=3, color=color_for_trainingset)

g.data = iris.iloc[:1]
# g.data = data[data['type'] == 'Target 1']
g.map_upper(sns.scatterplot, alpha=1, color='red')
g.map_lower(sns.scatterplot, alpha=1, color='red', zorder=3)

handles = [Line2D([], [], color='red', ls='', marker='o', label='target'),
           Line2D([], [], color=color_for_trainingset, lw=3, label='training set')]
g.add_legend(handles=handles)

plt.show()
```

[image: sns.pairplot with changed dataset]

Comment: Could this approach be extended to have a dual x-axis? Let's say we want to draw a different data column on the same grid plot in a different color instead of just one point.

Comment: @Shaun A dual x-axis would be more complicated, you'll probably need an explicit loop through the subplots. Also, a 2D kdeplot or scatterplot might be quite confusing with a dual x-axis.