# How to make black borders around certain markers in a seaborn pairplot

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have the following code:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

Data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['x1','x2','x3','label'])
for i in range(100):
    Data.loc[len(Data.index)] = [np.random.rand(),np.random.rand(),np.random.rand(),'1']

Data.loc[len(Data.index)] = [np.random.rand(),np.random.rand(),np.random.rand(),'2']
Data.loc[len(Data.index)] = [np.random.rand(),np.random.rand(),np.random.rand(),'3']
Data.loc[len(Data.index)] = [np.random.rand(),np.random.rand(),np.random.rand(),'4']
Data.loc[len(Data.index)] = [np.random.rand(),np.random.rand(),np.random.rand(),'5']

sns.pairplot(Data,vars=['x1','x2','x3'],hue='label',markers=['o','s','s','s','s'],corner=True)
```

Which gives the following output:
[image]

I want to put black borders only around the square markers to make them more visible but I don't know how to do that.

I tried to add:

```
grid_kws={fillstyles:['none','full','full','full','full']}
```

as an argument to sns.pairplot, but I just got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/spyder_kernels/py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File ~/Dokument/Python/MasterProjectCoCalc/SNmasterproject/untitled0.py:21
    sns.pairplot(Data,vars=['x1','x2','x3'],hue='label',markers=['o','s','s','s','s'],corner=True,grid_kws={fillstyles:['none','full','full','full','full']})

NameError: name 'fillstyles' is not defined
```

I also tried to add:

```
plot_kws={'edgecolor':'black'}
```

to the sns.pairplot function and then I got
[image]

but now all the points have a black border. How do I get only black borders around the square markers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scatter dots are stored in `ax.collections[0]`. To avoid that the colors of later hue values always come on top, seaborn keeps the dots in the order they appear in the dataframe. You can use `.set_edgecolors()` to set the  edge color of each individual dot.

For the legend, the dots in stored in its handles as `line` objects, which you can change via `.set_markeredgecolor(...)`

Here is how the code could look like:

```py
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

Data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'label'])
for i in range(100):
    Data.loc[len(Data.index)] = [np.random.rand(), np.random.rand(), np.random.rand(), '1']
Data.loc[len(Data.index)] = [np.random.rand(), np.random.rand(), np.random.rand(), '2']
Data.loc[len(Data.index)] = [np.random.rand(), np.random.rand(), np.random.rand(), '3']
Data.loc[len(Data.index)] = [np.random.rand(), np.random.rand(), np.random.rand(), '4']
Data.loc[len(Data.index)] = [np.random.rand(), np.random.rand(), np.random.rand(), '5']

g = sns.pairplot(Data, vars=['x1', 'x2', 'x3'], hue='label', markers=['o', 's', 's', 's', 's'], corner=True)

edge_colors = ['none' if l == '1' else 'k' for l in Data['label']]
for ax in g.axes.flat:
    if ax is not None and len(ax. Collections) > 0:
        ax.collections[0].set_edgecolors(edge_colors)
for h in g.legend.legend_handles[1:]:
    h.set_markeredgecolor('k')
```

[image: sns.pairplot change individual marker edge colors]

Comment: I like your answer better than my own, I recommend this one be accepted. Good answer mate

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, you cannot plot with different options using the `seaborn.pairplot` utility, you would have to create the graphs piecewise. [This excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71223682) shows how this can be done, but it's not super intuitive how to adapt that for your use case, so I have provided an example implementation to match your needs here with minor alterations from your original code.

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['x1','x2','x3','label'])
for i in range(100):
    Data.loc[len(Data.index)] = [np.random.rand(),np.random.rand(),np.random.rand(),'1']

Data.loc[len(Data.index)] = [np.random.rand(),np.random.rand(),np.random.rand(),'2']
Data.loc[len(Data.index)] = [np.random.rand(),np.random.rand(),np.random.rand(),'3']
Data.loc[len(Data.index)] = [np.random.rand(),np.random.rand(),np.random.rand(),'4']
Data.loc[len(Data.index)] = [np.random.rand(),np.random.rand(),np.random.rand(),'5']

# We will create the grid ourselves instead of using seaborn's utility
g = sns.PairGrid(Data.loc[Data['label'] == '1'], corner=True)
g.map_lower(sns.scatterplot)
g.map_diag(sns.kdeplot, fill=True)

# Since we are adding the data piecewise, we need to keep track of which ones got which colors
palette = sns.color_palette()
legend_labels = {'1': (palette[0], 'o')}

# Add each dataset piecewise
for i, label in enumerate(Data['label'].unique()):
    # Don't re-add group 1 again
    if label == '1':
        continue
    # Add the data, including the edge color
    g.data = Data.loc[Data['label'] == label]
    g.map_lower(sns.scatterplot, marker='s', edgecolor='black')
    # Track which color and marker we plotted with
    legend_labels[label] = (palette[i % len(palette)], 's')

# Add the legend with the colors and markers
# This line issues a warning you can ignore
g.add_legend(handles=[
    plt.Line2D(
        [], [], ls='', color=colormarker[0], marker=colormarker[1], label=label
    ) for label, colormarker in legend_labels.items()
])

plt.show()
```

And here is how it looks:
[image: Seaborn plot with varied markers and legend]

Let me know if you have any questions.